# Wait for textview to finish in python

Tags: python, textview, wait

I have a script that displays data in a textview box. 
It has multiple points that it updates the textview box.
My problem is that the textview box only updates after the sctipt has finshed. 
So how do I write text to the textview box then wait for that text to show then continue.
Thanks for the help.

```
self.textbuffer.insert_at_cursor("Keyword : " + var + "\n")
#....
#....Do some code here but wait for above to finish first
#....
self.textbuffer.insert_at_cursor("Result : " + "\n")
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code as an example?

Comment: I will soon I am at work atm.